# Jquery - add new rows table into wrong div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am pretty new to jquery. I have the following code. Here I wants to get new rows in the table on clicking add button in Fill 3. I succeend to add that row, but when I get new divs then I wants to get new rows in the table on clicking add button in Fill 3. It added into wrong div.

can someone tell me what mistake I've done here?

```js
var id = 0; //global id to create unique id

$(document).ready(function() {
  //attach click event to element/button with id add and remove
  $("#add,#remove").on('click', function() {
 var currentElemID = $(this).attr('id'); //get the element clicked

 if (currentElemID == "add") { //if it is add elem
   var cloneParent = $("#dataTes").clone(); //clone the dataTes element
   id=$("div[id^=dataTes]").length + 1;//get the count of dataTes element
   //it will be always more than last count each time
   cloneParent.find('[id]').each(function() {
    //loop through each element which has id attribute in cloned set and replace them 
    //with incremented value
  var $el = $(this); //get the element
  $el.attr('id', $el.attr('id') + id);
  //ids would now be add1,add2 etc.,
   });
   cloneParent.attr('id', cloneParent.attr('id') + id);//replace cloneParent id
   cloneParent.appendTo('#result');//append the element to fieldset
   $("#remove").show();//show remove button only if there is more than one dataTes element
 } else {
   $("div[id^=dataTes]:last").remove();
   //just remove the last dataTes
   //[id^=dataTes]:last annotates remove last div whose id begins with dataTes
   //remember we have id like dataTes1,dataTes2 etc
   if($("div[id^=dataTes]").length==1){
   //check if only one element is present
   $("#remove").hide();//if yes hide the remove button
   }
 }
  });

});

function addRow(tableID) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        }

    }

function deleteRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if (rowCount > 1) {
        table.deleteRow(rowCount - 1);
    }
    else {
        alert("Tidak dapat menghapus semua baris!");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="result">
  <legend>Test</legend>
  <input type="submit" class="button" id="add" value="+" title="#">
  <input type="submit" class="button" id="remove" value="-" style="display:none;" title="#">

  <!--hide the remove button with display:none initially-->

  <div id="dataTes">
<table align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin-top:10px;" width="97%">
  <tr>
    <td width="100px">Test</td>
    <td width="2px">:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="usrname">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <table align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin-top:5px;margin-left:40px;" width="97%">
    <tr>
      <td width="2px"></td>
      <td width="100px">Fill 1</td>
      <td width="2px">:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="usrname">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="2px"></td>
      <td width="100px">Fill 2</td>
      <td width="2px">:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="usrname">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <table id="dataIP" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin-left:40px;" width="97%">
      <tr>
        <td width="2px"></td>
        <td width="100px">Fill 3</td>
        <td width="2px">:</td>
        <td width="2px">
          <input type="text" name="usrname">
        </td>
  <td>
   <input type="submit" class="button" value="+" onClick="addRow('dataIP')" title = "#">
   <input type="submit" class="button" value="-" onClick="deleteRow('dataIP')" title = "#">
  </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </table>

</table>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="dataIP" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin-left:40px;" width="97%">
      <tr>
        <td width="2px"></td>
        <td width="100px">Fill 3</td>
        <td width="2px">:</td>
        <td width="2px">
          <input type="text" name="usrname">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="+" onClick="addRow('dataIP')" title = "#">
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="-" onClick="deleteRow('dataIP')" title = "#">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>`
```

---

so what will we do here is that we will change addRow(this) instead of addRow('dataIp') because we know that "this" keyword  has a high priority in terms of passing the ID of the element .. the "this" keyword has a general  purpose vs passing of id into a function .. just try changing all parameter to the "this".

Comment: it wont work, I think it need to check id of div elements @gideon

Comment: can you paste your latest code... i've tried to edit your code and it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addRow(tableID) {
  var par = tableID.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;
  var table = document.getElementById(par);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
}
```

> this is what ive done when I change the parameter of the add and delete function in your input i get the param parent node the element for the purpose of specific element inside the parent element...

}

Answer (score 0):

> by the way.. you must change your third index table to tbody. the result of getting the parentnode will be a tbody. because putting table inside a table is redundant window read it as tbody 
>   we must follow the rule 
>    `<table>
>         <tbody>
>         </tbody>
>         <tfoot>
>         </tfoot>
>      </table>`